# How to install PostgreSQL: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems

I'm getting the following error when running `bundle install`:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.21.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After this I tried running

```
gem install pg -v '0.21.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

which gave me this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200518-48011-1noawh0.rb extconf.rb
```

It also suggests look at `mkmf.log` file, which had:

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib -L. -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64   -lruby.2.6   "
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"xcrun clang -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS  -arch x86_64  -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

I'm not really sure how to fix this error. I guess it somehow checks in a wrong folder right? But not sure how to solve this.

I am using the Postgres app, and placed it in my Applications folder on my Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the Postgres source code and it's needed to compile the pg gem.

1. Install brew with

   ```
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install PostgreSQL server using

   ```
    brew install postgresql
   ```

But it also looks like you're using the built-in version of Ruby that ships with macOS. [Don't use system Ruby](https://dontusesystemruby.com/). I suggest installing a Ruby manager like RVM:

1. Install RVM with

   ```
    \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
   ```
2. Restart your shell.
3. Install Ruby with

   ```
    rvm install 2.7
   ```

Then reinstall your gems with `bundle install`.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/ruby-version-managers.html for a list of the choices, because there are many Ruby managers, RVM is only one, and anyone installing it should pay close attention to the documentation for [installation](https://rvm.io/install). On MacOS compiling the PG driver will also require installing Xcode and its command-line tools.